# Need assistance regarding In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Currently my is a paid app, now I am planning to make it free with limited functionality, after `in-app purchase` user can have full functionality. I want to know the people who have purchased previously can directly `restore purchase` so  they don't have to buy again.

Comment: You cant get that detail - unless you have some use default value in previous version storing version number.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't allow to make this automatically. You must do this in your code. For example check your apps version, like `version < x.y.z`  means that it was paid before, `version >= x.y.z` means this is a new user which should make the in-app-payment to unlock the full version.

Comment: If user downloaded the paid version, now app is free with limited functionality with in-app purchase, its easy to detect as you said by checking the version but if user has deleted an app and again installing it then how to detect that this particular user has paid already.......

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to get such things from Apple. But, you can do one things.

If you're having login feature then you can manage same things from date. So, for old registered need to show all features while new users need to show specific features only.